# Java recurrent task, problem with the dates

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to set a scheduled task in java for running once in a day.
The problem is that it is running only in the first day.
Any idea y?
Thanks

```
log.info("Schdualing midnight task");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    timer.schedule(new EndOfDayRatesTimerTask(new MidnightQuotesEvent()),
            date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) instead. For example,

```
TimerTask task = new EndOfDayRatesTimerTask(new MidnightQuotesEvent());
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, date.getTime(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the single-shot version of `schedule()`.  There's a version that takes an extra parameter to specify the delay between subsequent executions.